# React: When passing in a function to one instance of a component, why are all other instances effected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `handleFont` in the parent that increases font size.  I have a child component called `Child` and created 3 instances of it.  I passed the function `handleFont` from the `Parent` component into only *one* instance of the `Child` component however the function fires on mouseenter of all of them and also effects the font size of all of them.
Shouldn't it just be the one it's passed into to? Otherwise, how would it even be aware of what that function is referring to ?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   handleFont() {

       event.target.style.fontSize = "40px"
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <Child />
      <Child   
      />  
      <Child 
        handleFont = {this.handleFont}
      />
    </div>);
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
        let d = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0]
    d.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.props.handleFont)
  }
  render() {
    return <div>xxxx</div>
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code.

```
componentDidMount() {
        let d = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0]
    d.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.props.handleFont)
  }
```

The event is getting attached to the root div (container) holding all the child divs.

Following is the structure and where the event getting attached.

[image]

You need to attach the event specific to the child div to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: ah!  Thank you for explaining

Comment: hmm so I added a className to Child div called "child-container" and targeted it that way.  It works but only works once, meaning it if I have 3 child instances and pass the function in as a prop to each one, it will only work on the first one.  After inspecting the other 2 child divs, they don't even have the event listener attached to them.  Any idea why?

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting it correctly, can you please create it on stackblitz.com and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your `<Child handleFont = {this.handleFont} />` is mounted to the page you are selecting first `div` element on this page(probably root div). And adding a listener to it. So hovering all the page will cause `handleFont`.

In order to fix - do no do JS `addEventListener` in `componentDidMount, rather add this function to`div` you need

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  increaseFont = (event) => {
    if (this.props.handleFont) {
      this.props.handleFone(event)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div onMouseEnter={this.increaseFont}>xxxx</div>
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event's target is the container div.
You can try this out if you change your Child element to render something like return `<p>xxxx</div>`
and add an event listener on that element.